# What are the star/asterisks in a parameter in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to see all options of parameters in a Matplotlib method, for example, Axes.set_xticks(ticks, *, minor=False). What exactly is * and where can I view the options?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want the kwargs then [matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs//api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `*` delimits positional from [keyword-only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) arguments.

This means that you cannot hand over a value for `minor` by position but always have to use the `minor=<VALUE>` syntax in the call.

The only positional argument of this method is `ticks`, a list of floats.

Comment: Thank you! So if I want to find out my options, where should I go? Let's say I'm reading Matplotlib documentation, under what section/category do I need to look for them?

Comment: You could just follow the link to the web-based documentation in It_is_Chris' comment on your question or view python's builtin documentation: `help(Axes.set_xticks)`.